# Firefox driver won't connect using Serenity

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, serenity-bdd, webdrivermanager-java

I'm trying to run a simple test with Firefox, using Serenity.

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>serenity.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>firefox</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <serenity.version>1.4.0</serenity.version>
        <serenity.maven.version>1.4.0</serenity.maven.version>
        <webdriver.driver>firefox</webdriver.driver>

        <surefire.rerunFailingTestsCount>0</surefire.rerunFailingTestsCount>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/features/**/*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <webdriver.driver>${webdriver.driver}</webdriver.driver>
                        <surefire.rerunFailingTestsCount>${surefire.rerunFailingTestsCount}</surefire.rerunFailingTestsCount>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${serenity.maven.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
                        <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>serenity-reports</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-screenplay</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-screenplay-webdriver</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

And this is my test class:

```
public class FirefoxTest {

    @Managed
    WebDriver driver;

    private Actor actor;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        actor = Actor.named("Firefox user");
        actor.can(BrowseTheWeb.with(driver));
    }

    @Test
    public void open_browser(){
        actor.attemptsTo(Open.url("www.google.com"));
    }
}
```

Running "mvn verify" I get the following log:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building firefox 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ firefox ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ firefox ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ firefox ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\work\verso3\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ firefox ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.20:test (default-test) @ firefox ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running features.FirefoxTest
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.629 s <<< FAILURE! - in features.FirefoxTest
[ERROR] open_browser(features.FirefoxTest)  Time elapsed: 0.58 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at features.FirefoxTest.open_browser(FirefoxTest.java:31)

[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   FirefoxTest.open_browser:31 » NullPointer
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[ERROR] There are test failures.

Please refer to C:\work\verso3\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ firefox ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\work\verso3\target\firefox-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- serenity-maven-plugin:1.4.0:aggregate (serenity-reports) @ firefox ---
[INFO] current_project.base.dir: C:\work\verso3
[INFO] Generating test results for 0 tests
[INFO] 0 requirements loaded after 27 ms
[INFO] 0 related requirements found after 27 ms
[INFO] Generating test outcome reports: false
[INFO] Starting generating reports: 38 ms
[INFO] Configured report threads: 80
[INFO] Finished generating test results for 0 tests after 316 ms
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.337 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-08T13:20:18+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/274M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

So what's going on here? Why am I getting that null pointer exception? What am I doing wrong here?

The Firefox version I'm using is 53.0.3 (64-bit).

Answer (score 0):

It is probably an incompatible version of Firefox or gecko. But why are you managing the WebDriver instance yourself?

Comment: Ultimately I plan to manage the driver (or drivers) manually, because I intend to run tests on multiple browsers and include the results in a single report. But that's sort of beside the point so I changed the code to better reflect the Serenity Reference Manual (http://serenity-bdd.info/docs/serenity/#_building_serenity_projects_in_maven). My problem stayed basically the same, so would you please take another look at my question?